# Иерархия классов java

Tags: java, java-8

Есть какая-нибудь картинка где изображена иерархия встроенных классов в java?
От класса Object и все классы и интерфейсы, которые от него наследуются. А то когда читаешь книгу, пишут такой то класс наследуется от такого то и так далее. Потом эту иерархию представить себе не можешь. И каша в голове.

Answer (score 5):

Всех классов много, в одной картинке не уместить:

Иерархия класса Reader.

[image: Что-то важное]

Тут можно увидеть AWT:

[image]

Тут у нас потоки:

[image]

Считывание потоков:

[image]

Ошибки:
[image]

Немного io:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вообще, как мне кажется, нет смысла придумывать картинку, именно такую, какую ты хочешь. Ведь все классы наследуются от Object. Это все равно, что уместить все знания о Java в одном img.**

Answer (score 2):

Полная иерархия для всех пакетов:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-tree.html

В IntelliJ IDEA может так же пригодиться инструмент Type Hierarchy, Method Hierarchy, Call Hierarchy:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-structure-and-hierarchy-of-the-source-code.html